# GCP storage list_blobs with prefix and exclude a specific subfolder

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way of listing blobs with GCP python storage package under a specific folder, and excluding a specific subfolder path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API does not have an exclude option for prefixes.

Comment: Looks like the Edit queue is full, adding it as a comment. I have created [this Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/226454404) so the Cloud Storage team can add an Exclusion filter. Consider following up on that thread. Bear in mind that this does not guarantee that the Exclusion filter will be added or its ETA, but let's track the given thread and see how it goes.

Comment: @KevinQuinzel - What edit queue? Do not edit someone's answers. The correct procedure is to post a comment (as you did) or post another answer.